# What is the purpose of the contains() predicate in Mercurial Revision Sets?

Tags: mercurial

I can't think of cases where the contains() predicate is useful. It seems like the file(), adds(), removes() and modifies() predicates cover all file related queries. Can you give an example of when contains() is useful?

Answer (score 4):

Contains looks at content, not filenames:

```
"contains(pattern)"
  Revision contains pattern.
```

as compared to:

```
"file(pattern)"
  Changesets affecting files matched by pattern.
```

So something like:

```
hg log -r 'contains("spam")'
```

will show me all the changesets where the string spam is added or removed.  Note that the similar `keyword` command checks the commit message not the content.

Comment: You wrote: "Contains looks at content, not filenames": I must be doing something wrong because this is not what I experiment here. For me, it only outputs something when I use a file pattern as an argument. Also in TortoiseHG, this predicate is shown in the "File Pattern" category. My understanding of what contains() does is it outputs all the revisions where the repo contains a file that matches the given file pattern.

Comment: Hrm, I thought it was the analog of the 'hg grep' command.  I'll look at it again.